# Pandas: Grouping by list

Tags: python, pandas

I found one example of grouping in pandas by list

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
'data1': range(6),
'data2': rng.randint(0, 10, 6)},
columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])
L = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
print(df); print(df.groupby(L).sum())
```

Output is:

```
  key  data1  data2
0   A      0      5
1   B      1      0
2   C      2      3
3   A      3      3
4   B      4      7
5   C      5      9
   data1  data2
0      7     17
1      4      3
2      4      7
```

I couldn't understand how grouping by list is performed . Why i got such result?

Comment: Are you trying to do a custom sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the groupby does is get rows in `df` that pair with each value in `L`, before aggregating:

Pairings:

`0` is paired with rows 0, 2, 5, `,1` is paired with rows 1 and 3, while 2 is paired with row 4. You can see this from the groupby :

```
[*df.groupby(L)]
Out[111]: 
[(0,
    key  data1  data2
  0   A      0      5
  2   C      2      3
  5   C      5      9),
 (1,
    key  data1  data2
  1   B      1      0
  3   A      3      3),
 (2,
    key  data1  data2
  4   B      4      7)]
```

Once the pairing is assured, aggregation works out. Note that because it is `sum`, only numeric columns are retained. In future pandas version, you may have to explicitly state the columns to be aggregated.

Also note that the length of L has to match the number of rows in `df` or the groupby will fail.